PowerShell testing Application to run
I have  task where I need to open an application and login into to test if the app is running. I said to test if the process is running but it was discarded. In the top of my head I dont see how PowerShell can do this, but I would like a second opinion. Is this possible with PowerShell ?
Thanks

To ensure I understand your question correctly, you are seeking a PowerShell script to open an application, log into it, and then verify that the application is functioning correctly after login, without errors like "invalid user or password." Is that correct?  You may need to provide more info about the app.  If the makers of the app intend on it being automated, they may have documentation for doing it.  Additionally, the solution might vary depending on your operating system. Are you using Windows, Linux, or macOS? If it's Windows, which version of PowerShell are you using, 5.1 or 7.x.x?

Hi Darin, that is correct "open an application, log into it, and then verify that the application is functioning correctly after login, without errors like "invalid user or password."" I am using windows and powershell 7 . Do you think that is possible ?

We almost certainly need to look at the apps documentation.  It may support username and password as command line options, or credentials encrypted in a file on the system.   If not, then you may need to consider Quick Macros.  Quick Macros has a c like language that allows you to emulate mouse clicks, typing keyboard keystrokes and the ability to get some info related to the application's windows.   As for detecting success, the app would have to be called in such a way that powershell isn't froze and waiting for it to exit, and them maybe a call to Get-Process

If the app produces log files, it may log success or failure of login.  In that case, you might be able to monitor the log file and know the status of the app that way.

Thanls a lot Darin
